# django-elasticsearch-dsl: how to search across multiple documents?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have several ElasticSearch documents in Django describing each a different type of object: 'MovieDoc,' 'CartoonDoc,' etc. For now on, I can search across every such document individually:

```
document = MovieDoc
results = document.search().query('some phrase')
```

But what if I want to **search across all documents** at once and get the results altogether sorted by relevance (i.e. not searching every individual document and merging thereafter)?

I have tried something like this based on the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html) of elasticsearch-dsl, but this did not yield any results:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search    
results = Search(index=['movie_docs', 'cartoon_docs']).query('some phrase')
```

Comment: So, I figured out in the long run that sorting by relevance across multiple indices should be done using the dfs_query_then_fetch search type. However, it doesn't seem working in my case, so I've opened another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535042/elasticsearch-scoring-on-multiple-indexes-dfs-query-then-fetch-returns-the-same

Comment: More code would be nice, but wouldn't you want to get a queryset of all your documents and then pass it to Search, instead of writing 'movie_docs' etc... manually. you can convert a query set to a list of indexes if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard operator (`*`) as the index to search across all documents.

Implementation details may change over time. See the documentation on [Multi-target syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) for information pertaining to your version of Elasticsearch.

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch()

s = Search(using=client, index="*")

response = s.execute()

for hit in response:
    print(hit)
```