# Elasticsearch scoring on multiple indexes: dfs_query_then_fetch returns the same scores as query_then_fetch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have multiple indices in Elasticsearch (and the corresponding documents in Django created using django-elasticsearch-dsl). All of the indices have these settings:

```
    settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                'number_of_replicas': 0}
```

Now, I am trying to perform a search across all the 10 indices. In order to retrieve consistent scoring between the results from different indices, I am using **[dfs_query_then_fetch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch)**:

```
search = Search(index=['mov*'])
search = search.params(search_type='dfs_query_then_fetch')
objects = search.query("multi_match", query='Tom & Jerry', fields=['title', 'actors'])
```

I get bad results due to inconsistent scoring. A book called '*A story of Jerry and his friend Tom*' from one index can be ranked higher than the cartoon '*Tom & Jerry*' from another index. The reason is that **dfs_query_then_fetch** is not working. When I remove it or substitute with the simple **query_then_fetch**, I get absolutely the same results with the identical scoring.

I have tested it on URI requests as well, and I always get the same scores for both search types.

What can be the reason for it?

**UPDATE:** The results are actually not the same, but they are only *really slightly different*, e.g. a score of 50.1 with dfs and 50.0 without dfs, while the same model within one index has a score of 80.0.

Comment: Three months. Still no clue at all. Have tried asking on the Elasticsearch Discussion Forum but got no replies either.

Comment: Hey @Edmond, I have a similar problems. I have to search in multiple models which means I have multiple document class and multiple serializers. How to do that?? Have you solved it??

Answer (score 0):

If the number of shards is 1, then dfs_query_then_fetch and query_then_fetch will return the same result. DFS query will do a query to all shards and then show you results based on the scores computed, but in this case there is only one shard.

Regarding the scoring, you might wanna have a look at your actors field too. Also, do let us know what are the analyzer and tokenizer if you have used custom ones?

Comment: The number of shards is 1 for each particular index. Altogether, there are 8 shards, and  dfs_query_then_fetch should run, as per Elasticsearch's documentation. I am using the 'standard' analyzer.